# unwanted leading space inside data from a table column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

a column named `story` is a text type
clicking on a button I have a jquery ajax to get data from that column - on a specific `id`

```
<div id='bstory'></div>
```

on server side I have:

```
function a_click($id){
    global $db;
    $sq = "select story from dict where id = :aid limit 1";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([":aid" => $id]);
    echo $st->fetchColumn();
}
```

on client side:

```
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.post('a_dict_pro.php', {fn: 'a_click', args: [id]}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(bstory).text(data);
    });
});
```

everything works
problem - there is a leading space before `data`
on both places - `bstory` and `console`
for example if column content is `lorem ipsum` (without space) - I'm getting  `lorem ipsum`   (with space)
if I write `data = data.trim()` - there is no the space
I'm sure there is no that space inside the table column
pls help

Comment: Can you also include your jquery code wherever you are trying to access the data

Comment: @groovy_guy - I think it is not relevant, but it's here, I did

Comment: Are you able to provide the output of  `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @Reflective - as I said - ` lorem ipsum` - including the leading space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain the problem you have. When your PHP code is executed you may have some empty spaces, lines and other symbols before echoing and after echoing the output. The will be returned. So the things you should do is to assure  you don't have any spaces or lines before the `<?php` tag and to exit immediately after echoing your response i.e. something like echo `$st->fetchColumn(); exit;` or similar.

All this inconveniences could be saved if you output your result as a JSON string i.e. convert your fetched DB row to JSON string and set response headers to `application/json`; Than your `data` will be actually an Array or Object and during the JSON decode which will be made automatically by `$.post` even if you have spaces or other so called empty symbols they will be automatically stripped or ignored. For the JSON parser there's no significant difference if the string is `{}` or it is   `{}`   ;

I hope I described it well.

Now you know why passing a JSON as response is better than passing a simple string.

Comment: you're right - there was a space before the opening `<?php` tag. thanks a lot. I would never notice that. btw - why is that space echoed at all - it is not part of `echo` statement

Comment: The spaces before opening and closing tags are part of the file and normally they will appear in output.

Comment: hmm... there are a lot of another parts of that file - - functions, declarations, empty lines etc - and this is not the reason to be echoed. I think it should be echoed only the content inside the echo statement. It is a normal logic, isnt' it ?

Comment: Nope :) That's why API handlers should be at the beginning to avoid extra empty lines and etc i.e. the first thing in your php file should be `<?php`  .... then do what you do i.e. handle the request ... then setting of output headers , then `echo $result; exit; ?>`

Comment: empty spaces inside `<?php ?>` are not counted, but all spaces, lines and symbols outside them will appear in the output i.e. if all you have in a php file is 
` <?php echo 'hello';?> `  
both spaces before and after the php opening and closing tag will also be added to the output so you will  actually have as output 
' hello ', instead of 'hello'